# How to choose specific columns to textfile from datagrid c# winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

So I have a datagridProducts that I can export to text file but I don't want all the columns from the `DataGridView` to export, I wan't to be able to choose the columns that should go to the textfile, here is what I have now

```
StreamWriter sW = new StreamWriter("MyPathFile.txt");
string lines = "";
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridProducts.RowCount; i++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < dataGridProducts.ColumnCount; col++)
    {
        lines += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rader) ? ";" : ";") + 
           dataGridProducts.Rows[i].Cells[col].Value?.ToString();
    }
}
sW.WriteLine(rader);
sW.Close();
MessageBox.Show("The file is now exported");
```

Comment: You can do it using linq more elegant. But to correct your current code it's enough to add an `if` statement in second `for` loop and bypass those columns which you don't want, for example `if(col==1 || col==3) continue;`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei thank you but it don't work

Comment: Probably you didn't apply the criteria to bypass columns correctly. It's really simple and I believe it doesn't need an example. Anyway to use linq for selectiong values and to use `System.IO.File` I added an answer containing example.

Comment: Please don't remove code from question. It makes the question low quality and makes the answer nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correct your current code it's enough to add an `if` statement in second `for` loop and bypass those columns which you don't want, for example `if(col==1 || col==3) continue;`.

Also here is another option using `linq` to select desired columns and save them in file using `System.IO.File`:

```
var columns = new int[] { 0, 2 }; /* desired column indexes*/
var rows = dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => !r.IsNewRow)
    .Select(r => columns.Select(c => string.Format("{0}", r.Cells[c].Value)));
var headers = string.Join(";", columns.Select(i => dgv.Columns[i].HeaderText));
var lines = rows.Select(x => string.Join(";", x)).ToList();
lines.Insert(0, headers);
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"d:\file.txt", lines);
```

Comment: can you please show how you mean I will but the if statement in for loop it doesn't work

Comment: I'm not interested to use such way of string concatenation which you are using in your code. Also I'm not interested in using `StreamWriter` to save a simple text file. I believe the current answer is much better, so I prefer to don't touch the answer. Try it and let me know if you have any problem applying the solution :)

Comment: I tried it and It works exactly as I want it but I don't know where to put this string in your code because I want this to be written in the textfile. 
            sW.WriteLine("Response;product;customer;budget;");

Comment: Above code simply save some specific columns of `DataGridView` in a text file and it's what you are exactly asked for in the question. Can you say which part of the answer needs clarification? I'll try to help you if I can.

Comment: I also added column headers to the file.

Comment: Thank you! I want to write down my own headers not use the headers from the datagrid @RezaAghaei

Comment: Replace `var headers = ...`  with something which you want, for example `var headers ="blah;blah;"`

Comment: By the way, just for your information, when you accept an answer, it would be great if you also vote for answer by click on up arrow near it. It's a new permission for you since you've reached 15+ reputation.

Comment: I wasn't asking how to do it I was explaining to you what I have done... Thank you anyways bro:)

Comment: I just tried to be helpful. I removed the comment to not offend you :)

Comment: You did not offend me bro, I like you very helpful person. Have a great day/evening :)

Comment: It seems you have unaccepted the answer, Let me know if you have any other question about applying the answer.

Comment: U think you can help me with my new question?

Comment: Yes, I guess I can and I'll post an answer for you.

Comment: It's strange that you deleted the question! When someone takes some time to answer your question and provides some valuable answer for you, it's really strange and offensive to see the question has been deleted. You can ask additional questions if you need or just mark the post as answer if it answered your question.